# Space between two buttons

Tags: visualforce

I would like to add spacing between these two buttons in my VF page.

```
<a href="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/PD_TopNonMgrReport" class="button gold pull-right">{!$Label.PD_YourDash_TopNonMgr_ViewTop100}</a>

<a href="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/PD_Top20NonMgrReport" class="button gold pull-right">{!$Label.PD_YouDash_TopNonMgr_ViewTop20}</a>
```

Currently output is showing this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s2Ur.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `HTML` elements, you can use `CSS` to achieve this, This will also work with `<apex:SomeElement>`

Just use `style="left:xx;position:relative;"` where `xx` is the number of `px/dp` you want to add.

You can use it inline or add it to your style section

```
<a href="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/PD_TopNonMgrReport" style="left:0px;position:relative;" class="button gold pull-right">{!$Label.PD_YourDash_TopNonMgr_ViewTop100}</a>

<a href="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/PD_Top20NonMgrReport" style="left:20px;position:relative;" class="button gold pull-right">{!$Label.PD_YouDash_TopNonMgr_ViewTop20}</a>
```